# jQuery check if a P tag contains a A tag with a given id

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I have the following code I am trying to determine if the P tag contains a A tag with the id = Test1.  Thanks you.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p id="header"></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    // Append A tag with id= Test1
    $('#header').append("<a href='#' id='Test1'> Test1</a>")

    // If the p with id = header contains a A tag with id = Test1.
});
```

Comment: you are appending 'A' tag not determining it

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: you can do it like `if($("p#header a#Test1").length > 0){ /*do something*/ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the find method to check if the anchor tag with a given id is present.

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    // Append A tag with id= Test1
    $('#header').append("<a href='#' id='Test1'> Test1</a>")

    // If the p with id = header contains a A tag with id = Test1.
    if($('#header').find('a#Test1').length){
      alert('yes');
    }else {
      alert('no');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p id="header"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
if(!$( "p#header" ).has( "a#Test1" ).length){
   $('#header').append("<a href='#' id='Test1'> Test1</a>")
}else{
   //Your p element has this anchor with id test1
}
```

Comment: i haven't down voted it but i guess its because you are checking `a#test1`. But OP want it `a#Test1`

Comment: @Vineet Hi I just tried but it doesn't work. PS: I didn't marked you down.

Comment: @Ado I guess you first want to check whether `p` having `a` or not and then  try to append, right ?

Comment: @Vineet it worked, need be change to a#Test1 and I marked you up.  Thank you